# React Native Memory Leakage Animation Issue

Tags: android, ios, animation, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build a mobile pool game in React Native, 0.17, for experience and am running into problems concerning garbage collection. Right now I have ten circles that are being rendered simultaneously that bounce around the screen. However, memory consumption for the application is increasing over time and I don't know how to address this issue.

It seems like this was a React Native problem in earlier versions and I do notice falls in memory over time as shown in the graph here but in a much larger application, I am concerned that this may be issue. Has anyone else had similar issues or have solutions?

The relevant code is here and any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

var Test = React.createClass({

```
getInitialState: function() {
    var circs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < startCount; i++) {
        circs.push({
            id: i,
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            vx: 2 + Math.random() * 2,
            vy: 2 + Math.random() * 2,
            dx: 0,
            dy: 0,
            cOb: new Animated.ValueXY({x: 0, y: 0}),
        });
    }

    return {
        circles: circs,
        stop: 1
    };
},
stopCircle: function() {
    this.state.stop = -1 * this.state.stop;
    this.setState(this.state);
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.animateCircles();
},
animateCircles: function() {
    this.triggerAnimation(this.animateCircles);
},
triggerAnimation: function(ani) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.circles.length; i++) {
            var cCircle = this.state.circles[i];
            if (cCircle.x * cCircle.x + cCircle.y * cCircle.y > DIST_TO_EDGE * DIST_TO_EDGE) {
                var prevX = cCircle.x - cCircle.vx;
                var prevY = cCircle.y - cCircle.vy;
                var exitX = (1.5 * prevX + .5 * cCircle.x) / 2;
                var exitY = (1.5 * prevY + .5 * cCircle.y) / 2;
                cCircle.x = prevX;
                cCircle.y = prevY;

                var exitRad = Math.sqrt(exitX * exitX + exitY * exitY);
                exitX = exitX * DIST_TO_EDGE / exitRad;
                exitY = exitY * DIST_TO_EDGE / exitRad;

                var twiceProjFactor = 2 * (exitX * cCircle.vx + exitY * cCircle.vy) / (DIST_TO_EDGE * DIST_TO_EDGE);
                cCircle.vx = cCircle.vx - twiceProjFactor * exitX;
                cCircle.vy = cCircle.vy - twiceProjFactor * exitY;
                break;
            }
    }
    if (this.state.stop == 1) {
        for (var k = 0; k < this.state.circles.length; k++) {
            this.state.circles[k].x += this.state.circles[k].vx;
            this.state.circles[k].y += this.state.circles[k].vy;
        }
    }
    this.setState(this.state);
    var animateC = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.circles.length; i++) {
        var currCirc = this.state.circles[i];
        animateC.push(
            Animated.timing(currCirc.cOb, {
                ...TIMING_CONFIG,
                toValue: {x: currCirc.x, y: currCirc.y}
        }));
    }
    Animated.parallel(
        animateC
    ).start(ani);
},
getStyle: function(which) {
    return [
        styles.circle,
        {transform: this.state.circles[which].cOb.getTranslateTransform()}
    ];
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.edge}>
            </View>
            {
                this.state.circles.map(function(c, i) {
                    return (
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={i} onPress={this.stopCircle}>
                            <Animated.View style={this.getStyle(i)} />
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    );
                }, this)
            }
        </View>
    );
},
```

The full application can be found at https://github.com/heliumsoule/React-Native-Pool if you want to run the application for yourself.

Thank you again.

Comment: this.setState(this.state);  What does that do? I never came across that before.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of temporary variables, both simple numbers and objects. I'm not entirely sure if this ends up being frequently hit or if the animations span multiple frames. If it's every frame, I would guess you're just performing a ton of allocations. Those build up over time, and cause little pauses when the garbage collector is triggered.

To reduce the number of allocations, you could convert the temporary vars into instance variables, which can be reused.

I'm not familiar enough with the animation APIs to know if there are any optimizations there..

Comment: James, I've tried your suggestion and created instance variables rather than reallocating the variables but the memory usage still goes up (more gradually though).

Comment: Glad that helped a bit. Keep in mind that as long as you're doing allocations, you should expect memory to slowly creep up before being freed. That's just the way modern JS VMs work. It may be time to get familiar with debugging the memory. Once your app is running, take a couple snapshots. You can compare them to see what's growing the usage.

Answer (score 0):

You have two virtual machines that both perform garbage collection on their own terms.  The JVM and JavaScript.

This article might help you out:

http://moduscreate.com/dynamic-memory-and-v8-with-javascript/

Also, I suggest you comment out as much code as you can and see the effect on memory.  Then comment in a bit at a time and see which is the code that causes your memory consumption to grow most rapidly.

Comment: Michael, thanks for your article. I don't know if there are two VMs because JavaScript is being rendered here in a React Native framework. I know that the main memory consumption is with the triggerAnimation method which is called every TIMING_CONFIG, which just specifies the time between calls. However, I don't know how to further optimize the code after James' suggestion.

Comment: I'm not an android expert, but the React Native framework is Java and the JS engine used to execute the React Native code is V8.  Your app is calling Java from JavaScript and vice versa.

What happens if you let the program run for a very long time?  Both Java and V8 might defer some of their garbage collection until the device is low on memory or the process is using its limit.